# Getting C2027 use of undefined type 'dlib::image_traits<image_type>' error when using dlib::frontal_face_detector

Tags: c++, dlib

I am using the latest version of dlib and trying to build a DLL that detects faces using its `dlib::frontal_face_detector` and `dlib::shape_predictor predictor`. However,
upon trying to use the `detector` by simply doing :

```cpp
auto faces = this->detector(img, 0);
```

I get this compilation error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'pixel_type'    Test    D:\Codes\Dependencies\include\dlib\image_processing\scan_fhog_pyramid.h 601 
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Test    D:\Codes\Dependencies\include\dlib\image_processing\scan_fhog_pyramid.h 601 
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'dlib::image_traits<image_type>'  Test    D:\Codes\Dependencies\include\dlib\image_processing\scan_fhog_pyramid.h 601
```

This is how the code looks like :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#include <functional>

//#include <torch/torch.h>
//#include <torch/script.h>


#include <dlib/opencv.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>

//#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

class TEST_API Test
{
public:
    Test(std::string shape_predictor_path = "");
    void main_op(cv::Mat img_ori, bool show_debug_info = true);
    ~Test();

private:
    dlib::frontal_face_detector detector;
    dlib::shape_predictor predictor;
    //torch::jit::script::Module net;
};
```

```cpp
//in Test.cpp
#include <Test/Test.h>
Test::Test(std::string shape_predictor_path)
{
    auto cdir = fs::current_path();
    detector = dlib::get_frontal_face_detector();

    auto landmark_path = shape_predictor_path == "" ? (cdir / "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat").string() : shape_predictor_path;
    auto model_path = (cdir / "net_4.jit").string();
    std::cout << "landmark path: " << landmark_path << "model path: " << model_path << std::endl;
    dlib::deserialize(landmark_path) >> this->predictor;
    //this->net = torch::jit::load(model_path);
}
void Test::main_op(cv::Mat img, bool show_debug_info)
{
    try
    {
        //cv::Mat img_cpy(img);
        //grayscale
        cv::cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        auto faces = this->detector(img, 0);
         //....
    }
    catch(std::exception exp)
    {
        std::cout << exp.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm using OpenCV3.4.11 along-side libtorch1.6 in Visual Studio 2019. and The language is set to C++17.
I also have these in my C++ preprocessors :

```
NDEBUG
_CONSOLE
_SILENCE_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATION_WARNING
_SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

I'm using dlib 19.21 and I included its include path and added dlibs `source.cpp` to the dll project of mine and build my project like this.
These are also my build options :

```
/D_TEST_BUILD_DLL  /bigobj
```

Why am I seeing this error? What am I missing here?

### Update:

Without using any other libraries such as torch, this happens again. so this is not related to any other libraries. this is pure dlib/opencv!

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], your question is off-topic without it.

Comment: The question is not off-topic regardless of providing a mre or not. in this case it was not needed imo. in case it was needed, downvoting wouldnt help it.

Comment: A [mcve] is a tool that makes sure that questions have a certain quality. Your question lacks quality as the unknown code causes multiple errors. That's too many question marks and that's the reason a downvote is justified IMHO. I'd have cut you some slack if you were a new user here, but you're here long enough to know these things.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I'm not going to argue with you here, for the very same reason that you also just mentioned, I did not think it as necessary, as the bulk of the code shown here is actually the main operations responsbile for the result. there is not a single dependency that affects the operation in question. This is the MRE! if you look at it again. I just added those `extra` information, in case, there is a conflict of libs sth like that. 
As you can see, the issue was simply related to the lack of proper conversion. regardless of  this , Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was kind of misleading, The issue was caused by feeding a `cv::Mat` to the  `dlib::get_frontal_face_detector()` and `dlib::shape_predictor` objects, resulting in the stated error. Converting it to the expected type solved the issue:

```cpp
dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> img_dlib;
dlib::assign_image(img_dlib, dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel>(img));
auto faces = this->detector(img_dlib, 0);
```

More specifically as we were converting the input image into grayscale we can simply use `cv_image<unsigned char>` instead:

```cpp
dlib::array2d<unsigned char> img_dlib;
dlib::assign_image(img_dlib, dlib::cv_image<unsigned char>(img));
auto faces = this->detector(img_dlib, 0);
```

### Side note

It actually  took me the next 14 hours to reach the same solution I initially posted because I completely missed the input to the `dlib::shape_predictor`, since when I changed the detectors input from `cv::Mat` to `dlib::array2d` and the error still remained! I thought that wasn't the case and started a 14 hours marathon of building and rebuilding in different flavors and using different approaches to ultimately reach this point!

So as a rule of thumb, feed all dlib related methods, the dlib array2d! I have no idea why it does not issue a compilation error when this happens.
Were dlib to specifically issue an error in such cases, we wouldn't be facing such issues.

Here is the sample approach one can take to build dlib and use it in a Visual Studio (in my case, I used it to create a DLL):
[Part1-Building Dlib using Visual Studio 2019](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5382892/90326738-30391f00-dfa1-11ea-85a9-aeb257160bd4.gif)

[Part2-Using it in a DLL project](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5382892/90326740-329b7900-dfa1-11ea-9d16-c34dc1c22228.gif)